# How to use binaries?

Tags: software-installation, binary

I installed SQLite and SQLite3 from the software center. It works, but the SQLite3 version is from 2013.

I tried to install the binaries that are available directly from SQLite. I downloaded the "Precompiled Binaries for Linux" (https://sqlite.org/download.html). However, at this point I have no idea how to install/use these files. They are not *.deb or *.rpm and from what I can see they have no extension.

I suspect I need to put these files somewhere (but have no idea where). Could you please suggest how to use these files?

I am using 14.04 on a 64 bit machine. If I may provide any additional information please let me know.

Items I have tried so far:

1. I searched my computer for files with the same name as the files I downloaded (so i could replace old files with new files), but i did not find anything
2. Tried to install files using dpkg -i
3. Tried to run the files by right clicking and selecting 'Run'
4. Searched all over askubuntu.com, sqlite.org and the web in general.

still no luck.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to want to install newer versions? If not, the ones in the repositories should work well enough.

Comment: @fkraiem When i read the documentation on sqlite.org it mentions commands which are not present for me in the version I am using. As well, I am hoping to improve my understanding of Ubuntu.